# Need resources/template/engine for html5/js board game (javascript/jquery/rails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, game-engine

I'd like to build a very basic board game (chess-like board with square tiles) with a tile-based board where users clicks each tile and discovers if it is a winning or losing tile.

As I am just beginning with javascript, i'd like to find a resource giving guidelines to create such a board game, it could be a open source gist, a game i could extract the html/js to get inspiration or a game itself that shares how it has been made... anything really.

What I need is to understand how to create the board, how to make effects on tiles when users hover on a tile/select a tile/a tile has already been searched, and also see how people manage in JavaScript player collision (if many players try to go on the same tile at the same time).

Any ideas where i could find such resources or examples of such game?

Comment: I programmed a Nine Men's Morris game a few semesters ago. It uses jquery for the effects and plain HTML/CSS for the GUI. I coded this prior to using a more object oriented style of javascript, so it is VERY messy, but it is fairly easy to follow. Feel free to view the source code. http://cse.unl.edu/~emitchel/csce361.homepage.pt.html

Comment: I'd recommend a framework such as [CreateJs](http://www.createjs.com/) - I recently developed [this game](https://apps.facebook.com/lock-a-door/) using it and it was very easy to use